# Show code with the "<"-char as literal text in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, decode, encode

How can I display the value `"<My comment"` in a asp.net textbox. I used Server.HtmlEncode(string) but now I see all the html codes. I want the above text literally to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

see this http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&#60;` for the less than sign and `&#62;` for more than..

So it would be like

```
\"&lt;My Comment\"
```

Comment: If you have an update to your own post, it is better to edit the post than to add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`<`, or in other words `&lt;`

Comment: but Server.HtmlEncode works without having to resort to this !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
myText.Text = "&lt;My Comment";
```

PS please click the checkmark of an answer so we know you have your solution.